# group by 2 columns python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of shape :

```
 id | V
 1    0
 2    1
 3    0
 4    0
 1    0
 2    0
 4    1
```

where V is only 1 or 0 and id can have duplicates. What i want is for each id to count 0s and 1s. Example above would be

```
    1 : ('0':2,'1':0)
    4 : ('0':1,'1':1)
    3 : ('0':1,'1':0)
    2 : ('0':1,'1':1)
```

i don't care about the format of the result this is just an example. It could be a dataframe with 0 and 1 as columnns or whatever.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've guessed the `pandas` tag. Please change if `pandas` is incorrect, but include a tag for the framework as `dataframe` is ambiguous.

Comment: `('0':2,'1':0)` is not a valid python object, do you mean `{'0':2,'1':0}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `value_counts` method.

Example:

```
df.groupby("id").V.value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Json format. You can do this.

```py
df.groupby(['id','V'])['V'].count().unstack().T.fillna(0).astype(int).to_json()
```

Output:

```py
{
  "1":{"0":2,"1":0},
  "2":{"0":1,"1":1},
  "3":{"0":1,"1":0},
  "4":{"0":1,"1":1}
}
```